# IPC: 32 bit process trigger 64 bit process (windows)

Tags: windows, ipc, native, 32bit-64bit

**Environment:**
Two processes: one 32 bit and the other 64 bit (Both C++ native, VS2013)

**Question:**
What is the best way to trigger the 64 bit process to execute functions (including function arguments) by the 32 bit process?